# im trying to make this through react-quill npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-quill, react-quilljs

[image]

Currently, both appear as columns.

In the browser, `react-quill` built-in classes like `class="ql-toolbar ql-snow"` and `class="ql-container ql-snow"` take separate space which I don't require (I think so).

I'm expecting both, the toolbar and container to appear as image.